# Searchkick End of File Reached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick, opensearch

In my Rails 7.0.1 app with Ruby 3.0.3 I get this error when performing a search with SearchKick:

> 19:13:13 web.1    | Started GET "/search?q=nemesis" for ::1 at
> 2022-01-24 19:13:13 +0000 19:13:13 web.1    | Processing by
> SearchController#index as HTML 19:13:13 web.1    |   Parameters:
> {"q"=>"nemesis"} 19:13:13 web.1    | Completed 500 Internal Server
> Error in 32ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 4163) 19:13:13 web.1
> | 19:13:13 web.1    | 19:13:13 web.1    | 19:13:13 web.1    |
> Faraday::ConnectionFailed (end of file reached): 19:13:13 web.1    |
> 19:13:13 web.1    | app/controllers/search_controller.rb:20:in `index'

My controller for search looks like:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if params[:q].present?
      query_string = ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate(params[:q]).gsub('/', '\\/')
      type = params[:type]
      where = {}

      if type
        where[:type] = type
      end

      @results = Searchkick.search query_string, models: [Coaster, Park, Ride, Album], where: where, aggs: [:type], misspellings: {edit_distance: 1}, match: :word_start, load: true

      if @results.count == 1
        result = @results.first
        if result.class.to_s.underscore.downcase == 'coaster'
          redirect_to park_coaster_path(result.park, result)
        end

        if result.class.to_s.underscore.downcase == 'park'
          redirect_to park_path(result)
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

I'm running OpenSearch in Docker and the entry for it in my Docker Compose file is:

```yaml
  search:
    image: 'opensearchproject/opensearch:1.2.4'
    restart: always
    env_file:
        - .env
    environment: # https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/opensearch/install/docker/#sample-docker-compose-file-for-development
        - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster
        - node.name=opensearch-node1
        - bootstrap.memory_lock=true # along with the memlock settings below, disables swapping
        - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" # minimum and maximum Java heap size, recommend setting both to 50% of system RAM
        - "DISABLE_INSTALL_DEMO_CONFIG=true" # disables execution of install_demo_configuration.sh bundled with security plugin, which installs demo certificates and security configurations to OpenSearch
        - "DISABLE_SECURITY_PLUGIN=true" # disables security plugin entirely in OpenSearch by setting plugins.security.disabled: true in opensearch.yml
        - "discovery.type=single-node" # disables bootstrap checks that are enabled when network.host is set to a non-loopback address
    volumes:
        - search-volume:/usr/share/opensearch/data:rw,delegated
    ports:
        - '9200:9200'
```

Any suggestions?